# Нестандартная рамка для img

Tags: css

есть такая рамка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли силами css сделать ее, чтобы в нее спокойно помещать картинки. То есть к примеру картинка квадратная, но она смотрелась именно так.
И если нет, но имеется рамка в виде .png, то можно ли сделать также, и чтобы квадратные картинки не выходили за рамки соответственно.

Comment: Если делать через CSS, то в многих браузерах данный шестигрань не будет показыватся, лучше для контейнера картинки, установить PNG бекграунд  + свойство overflow:hidden; а вот в нутри просто вставить тег IMG (картинку)

Comment: пнг имеет прозрачный фон и по сути только линии эти. разве overflow: hidden поможет?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону SVG графики https://htmlweb.ru/html/graph.php

Comment: если фон всегда черный, делайте наружную часть рамки черной и всё

Comment: фон может быть разного цвета, поэтому это не подходит =(

Comment: добавление стиля с параметром
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
частично решило проблему, но не могу создать границу и размер стандартный чтобы был

Comment: @PaulWall, я логику написал как можно сделать, сейчас пример на скорую руку покажу

Comment: как я понял - svg действительно жестко решает, но я пока не разобрался как правильно это использовать

Answer (score 1):

Это простой пример, показал чтобы логика была понятна... использовал что попалось под руку ))

```css
.main{
    width: 460px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
}


.wrapper{
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:9;
background:url(https://mrpsmythopedia.wikispaces.com/file/view/Beowulf-king-geats.jpg/571579007/Beowulf-king-geats.jpg) no-repeat;

}


.box{
z-index:99;
overflow:hidden;
width: 489px;
height: 468px;
position:relative;
background:url('http://mirgif.com/ramki/ramka-47.gif');
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="box">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну самый лучший способ это реализовать не на Эксперементальных стилях Chromium а именно на SVG, это будет примерно так :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="0 0 1000 300"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8">
  <defs>
  <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="380" height="480">
    <image xlink:href="http://gamebomb.ru/files/galleries/001/f/f2/170863_w350_h250_f.jpg" x="0" y="-53" width="380" height="480" />
  </pattern>
</defs>
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <path
       style="stroke-width:10.00000028;fill:url(#img1);stroke:#00bc00;"
       d="M 18.142852,202.50594 18.327494,97.864713 109.04177,45.704005 199.57141,98.184522 199.38677,202.82575 108.67249,254.98646 Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот что придумал

```
<div class="nub"><div class="ub"><img src="http://jd3sljkvzi-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/cloudraider_622.jpg" height="100%"></div></div>

.nub {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #999933 0%, #666633 20%, #000000 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
.ub { 
    position: relative;
    top: 1%;
    left: 1%;
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bkj7t1jw/1/

вроде бы все готово =) теперь можно с рамочкой баловаться градиентами =)